# When creating a view for an original table, how to use the same FK to another table in entity framework fluent mapping

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to set up fluent mapping for an entity that is for a view.  The problem is, I have a table that is similar to the view (that the view is for - the difference is the view adds some aggregated columns on to the end), and an entity for that, so I can have a FK to the same child table of it.  I want both the view and the table to be able to have the same child list definition, but EF doesn't like it, because it will not allow both the entity for the view and the entity for the table to use the same named foreign key, but I need to.  How can I get around this?

i.e.

```
  public class ViewEntity
  {
      public ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get;set;}
  }

  public class TableEntity
  {
      public ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildEntities { get;set;}
  }

  public class ChildEntity
  {
      public int TableEntityId { get; set; } 
  }
```

Comment: ChildEntity, for table Child has the TableEntityId column, and it is a real FK to Table (for TableEntity entity), but since ViewEntity is for a View that has all the columns of Table plus a few more, I need it to also be able to reference ChildEntity by TableEntityId (so I can load a bunch of Child records to Table into my ViewEntity's ChildEntities collection).  I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: If you need the `TableEntity` only for create/update/delete you could read and display `ViewEntity`s and attach to the `TableEntities` set in the context for CUD actions.

Comment: How would I go about doing that - I sort of tried adding a property to ViewEntity called TableEntity and a property to TableEntity called ViewEntity so they could reference each other.  And then I added this as a mapping to my context: modelBuilder.Entity<TableEntity>().HasRequired(e => e.ViewEntity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.Id); ...but I get an exception doing that (I think maybe because Id on ViewEntity somehow gets set as a primary key in my mapping ..Id on ViewEntity and TableEntity are the same)

Comment: I don't know what kind op application you're in, but usually there are distinct read and write paths, as in Get methods and Save methods. A save method could accept a ViewEntity that gets mapped to a TableEntity which is attachted to the context and saved.

Comment: And, forgot to say, use a `TableEntity` without `ChildEntities`. In CUD operations use the ChildEntities of `ViewEntity`.

Comment: So I was able to get this working ...and basically with this mapping:  modelBuilder.Entity<ViewEntity>().HasRequired(e => e.TableEntity).WithOptional(e2 => e2.ViewEntity); ...so ViewEntity has a TableEntity property and TableEntity has a ViewEntity property.  It's weird though - whenever I do a query to TableEntity that needs to check a field on ViewEntity in the query, the generated sql joins to my View twice.  Any ideas??  Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can post this as an answer to your own question (it is OK to do that).

Comment: But I'm thinking I haven't gotten something right here, since it joins to the view twice whenever I query Table based on a field in the View.